# jScrollPane overflow issue in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, overflow, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane on a client site and thought all was good until I tested in IE7.  It seems that for some reason the pane isn't hiding the overflow.  IE8 and all Mac browsers are fine.  IE7 is the problem. Scrollbar shows up just fine, but the content (a long ul) is flowing outside of the div, and causing the main page to have scrollbars as well. See what I mean here:

http://mhr.dandelion-patch.com

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code
.scroll-pane-left, .scroll-pane-left2 {width:100%; height:280px; overflow: auto;position: relative;}

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I had given up long ago.  This worked!